# Flutter 'Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.' when coming back from 'showSearch'

Tags: flutter

We have a UI that shows a list with many items, and we want to be able to sort them easily. We are already using a `ReorderableListView` but as it requires the user to drag, it doesn't really work well for lists with many items. We came with the idea of using search for it in the following way:

1. In the first step, the user is allowed to reorder items by dragging, but is also able to click the leading `IconButton` to select the 'source' item for moving. To help quickly pick the correct 'source' item, the user is allowed to search/filter shown items by a query.
2. Selecting a 'source' item in step 1 triggers the second step: a list with the same data is shown (with the item selected in step 1 disabled), and the user can click the leading `IconButton` to select the 'target' item. To help quickly pick the correct 'target' item, the user is allowed to search/filter shown items by a query.
3. Selecting a 'target' item triggers step 3: a small dialog is shown so that the user can choose if the 'source' item from step 1 should be put before or after the 'target' item from step 2.
4. Once picked, the logic (using a BLoC in my case) is triggered.

Step 1 and 2 are implemented using Flutters `showSearch` functions with delegates, i.e. picking an item in search in step 1 starts a new 'child' search with a fresh delegate. Please take a look at the following GIF, where I first choose 'source' 'Item 0' in step 1, then 'target' 'Item 4' in step 2, and then 'After' in step 3:

[image]

In general this works the way we want it to if we pass the BLoC instance and don't look it up using the context. However, we do want to use the context as the real app is much more complicated and passing the BLoC around is not viable. However, using `context.read` causes the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
#0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3906
#1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3920
#2      Element.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3986
#3      Provider._inheritedElementOf
package:provider/src/provider.dart:324
#4      Provider.of
package:provider/src/provider.dart:281
#5      ReadContext.read
package:provider/src/provider.dart:614
#6      SortingTile._moveItem
package:flutter_test_app/main.dart:80
<as<…>
```

For the life of me, I can't get it to work. I tried adding the `Builder` widget here and there to get a different context instance, but it just won't work.

Here is the complete code (the line causing the error marked with `<--- HERE`), it is a bit lengthy so please let me know if I should upload it somewhere. I don't think I can make it much shorter and still be able to reproduce the issue (maybe I could, but I don't understand it, so there is that). Actually the first half of `main.dart` is interesting, the rest is the BLoC etc. which works and probably is irrelevant, but who knows. The code should run without issues with Flutter 1.22.5.

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
name: flutter_sorting_app
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  bloc: ^6.1.0
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

main.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => DataBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [
              Builder(
                builder: (context) => IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<DataBloc>().add(DataRequested());
                    showSearch(
                      context: context,
                      delegate: SortingSearchDelegate(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// SearchDelegates

// Step 1 - sort by drag & drop (no step 2 necessary) or pick the item to move

class SortingSearchDelegate extends DataBlocSearchDelegate<DataBloc, void> {
  @override
  Widget buildListDataWidget(BuildContext context, List<IndexedItem> data) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: (from, to) {
        context.read<DataBloc>().add(DataItemPositionChanged(from, to));
      },
      children: data.map((indexedItem) => SortingTile(indexedItem)).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class SortingTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final IndexedItem indexedItem;

  SortingTile(this.indexedItem) : super(key: ValueKey(indexedItem.item));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () => _moveItem(context),
        icon: Icon(Icons.swap_vert),
      ),
      title: Text('${indexedItem.item}'),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _moveItem(BuildContext context) async {
    // Trigger step 2.
    // There is no need to request any data, the same BLoC is reused.
    final insertionPoint = await showSearch(
      context: context,
      delegate: InsertionPointPickerSearchDelegate(indexedItem.index),
    );
    if (insertionPoint != null) {
      var targetIndex = insertionPoint.index;
      if (insertionPoint.placement == Placement.after) {
        ++targetIndex;
      }
      context
          .read<DataBloc>() // <--- HERE
          .add(DataItemPositionChanged(indexedItem.index, targetIndex));
    }
  }
}

// Step 2 - pick placement of picked item in step 1

enum Placement { before, after }

class InsertionPoint {
  final Placement placement;
  final int index;

  InsertionPoint(this.placement, this.index);
}

class InsertionPointPickerSearchDelegate
    extends DataBlocSearchDelegate<DataBloc, InsertionPoint> {
  final int movedItemIndex;

  InsertionPointPickerSearchDelegate(this.movedItemIndex);

  @override
  Widget buildListDataWidget(BuildContext context, List<IndexedItem> listData) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final indexedItem = listData[index];

        return ListTile(
          enabled: indexedItem.index != movedItemIndex,
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_alt),
          ),
          title: Text(indexedItem.item),
          onTap: () => _pickPlacement(context, indexedItem.index),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // Step 3
  Future<void> _pickPlacement(BuildContext context, int index) async {
    final placement = await showDialog<Placement>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('Before'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(Placement.before),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('After'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(Placement.after),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    if (placement != null) {
      close(context, InsertionPoint(placement, index));
    }
  }
}

// DataBloc
// Events

abstract class DataEvent {}

class DataRequested extends DataEvent {}

class DataItemPositionChanged extends DataEvent {
  final int fromIndex;
  final int toIndex;

  DataItemPositionChanged(this.fromIndex, this.toIndex);
}

// States

abstract class DataState {}

class DataInitial extends DataState {}

class DataLoadingInProgress extends DataState {}

class DataLoadingSuccess extends DataState {
  final List<String> listData;

  DataLoadingSuccess(this.listData);
}

// BLoC

class DataBloc extends Bloc<DataEvent, DataState> {
  DataBloc() : super(DataInitial());

  @override
  Stream<DataState> mapEventToState(DataEvent event) async* {
    if (event is DataRequested) {
      yield DataLoadingInProgress();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      yield DataLoadingSuccess(List.generate(5, (index) => 'Item $index'));
    } else if (event is DataItemPositionChanged) {
      yield* _mapPositionChanged(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<DataState> _mapPositionChanged(DataItemPositionChanged event) async* {
    final successState = state as DataLoadingSuccess;
    final listData = [...successState.listData];
    final item = listData.removeAt(event.fromIndex);

    var to = event.toIndex;
    if (event.fromIndex < to) {
      // When moving to a later index, the list has just been made smaller
      // by 1 (the removal above) so decrease the target index.
      to -= 1;
    }
    listData.insert(to, item);

    yield DataLoadingSuccess(listData);
  }
}

// DataBlocSearchDelegate

class IndexedItem {
  final String item;
  final int index;

  IndexedItem(this.item, this.index);
}

abstract class DataBlocSearchDelegate<DB extends DataBloc, R>
    extends SearchDelegate<R> {
  Widget buildListDataWidget(BuildContext context, List<IndexedItem> listData);

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () => close(context, null),
      icon: const BackButtonIcon(),
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () => query = '',
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<DB, DataState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        Widget body;
        if (state is DataLoadingSuccess) {
          body = buildListDataWidget(
            context,
            state.listData
                .asMap()
                .entries
                .map((e) => IndexedItem(e.value, e.key))
                .where((indexedItem) => indexedItem.item
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                .toList(),
          );
        } else if (state is DataInitial || state is DataLoadingInProgress) {
          body = Text('Loading...');
        } else {
          body = Text('Invalid state: $state');
        }
        return body;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason is that once the second `showSearch` call is made, all widgets built to show the UI of the first one are disposed (which is due to the internally used route having `maintainState` set to `false`). This means that once the result from the second search is returned and I try to get the BLoC from the context, the context is stale, hence the error.

We've tried various solutions to make Flutter preserve the state, including `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, but nothing would work.

In the end a viable solution in our case was to restructure the code a bit and perform BLoC lookup deeper, in the second search, instead of returning the result and executing the moving logic in the first one. In our real app it has the disadvantage that we need to carry some data with us to the second search, but we got nothing better than this...

Here is the complete changed and working code in case someone is interested (diff against the first version to see exactly how exactly we fixed the issue):

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => DataBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [
              Builder(
                builder: (context) => IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<DataBloc>().add(DataRequested());
                    showSearch(
                      context: context,
                      delegate: SortingSearchDelegate(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// Delegates

// Step 1 - sort by drag & drop (no step 2 necessary) or pick the item to move

class SortingSearchDelegate extends DataBlocSearchDelegate<DataBloc, void> {
  @override
  Widget buildListDataWidget(BuildContext context, List<IndexedItem> data) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: (from, to) {
        context.read<DataBloc>().add(DataItemPositionChanged(from, to));
      },
      children: data.map((indexedItem) => SortingTile(indexedItem)).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class SortingTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final IndexedItem indexedItem;

  SortingTile(this.indexedItem) : super(key: ValueKey(indexedItem.item));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () => _moveItem(context),
        icon: Icon(Icons.swap_vert),
      ),
      title: Text('${indexedItem.item}'),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _moveItem(BuildContext context) {
    // Trigger step 2.
    // There is no need to request any data, the same BLoC is reused.
    return showSearch(
      context: context,
      delegate: InsertionPointPickerSearchDelegate(indexedItem.index),
    );
  }
}

// Step 2 - pick placement of picked item in step 1

enum Placement { before, after }

class InsertionPointPickerSearchDelegate
    extends DataBlocSearchDelegate<DataBloc, void> {
  final int movedItemIndex;

  InsertionPointPickerSearchDelegate(this.movedItemIndex);

  @override
  Widget buildListDataWidget(BuildContext context, List<IndexedItem> listData) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final indexedItem = listData[index];

        return ListTile(
          enabled: indexedItem.index != movedItemIndex,
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_alt),
          ),
          title: Text(indexedItem.item),
          onTap: () => _pickPlacement(context, indexedItem.index),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // Step 3
  Future<void> _pickPlacement(BuildContext context, int index) async {
    final placement = await showDialog<Placement>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('Before'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(Placement.before),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('After'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(Placement.after),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    if (placement != null) {
      if (placement == Placement.after) {
        ++index;
      }
      context
          .read<DataBloc>()
          .add(DataItemPositionChanged(movedItemIndex, index));
      close(context, null);
    }
  }
}

// DataBloc
// Events

abstract class DataEvent {}

class DataRequested extends DataEvent {}

class DataItemPositionChanged extends DataEvent {
  final int fromIndex;
  final int toIndex;

  DataItemPositionChanged(this.fromIndex, this.toIndex);
}

// States

abstract class DataState {}

class DataInitial extends DataState {}

class DataLoadingInProgress extends DataState {}

class DataLoadingSuccess extends DataState {
  final List<String> listData;

  DataLoadingSuccess(this.listData);
}

// BLoC

class DataBloc extends Bloc<DataEvent, DataState> {
  DataBloc() : super(DataInitial());

  @override
  Stream<DataState> mapEventToState(DataEvent event) async* {
    if (event is DataRequested) {
      yield DataLoadingInProgress();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      yield DataLoadingSuccess(List.generate(5, (index) => 'Item $index'));
    } else if (event is DataItemPositionChanged) {
      yield* _mapPositionChanged(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<DataState> _mapPositionChanged(DataItemPositionChanged event) async* {
    final successState = state as DataLoadingSuccess;
    final listData = [...successState.listData];
    final item = listData.removeAt(event.fromIndex);

    var to = event.toIndex;
    if (event.fromIndex < to) {
      // When moving to a later index, the list has just been made smaller
      // by 1 (the removal above) so decrease the target index.
      to -= 1;
    }
    listData.insert(to, item);

    yield DataLoadingSuccess(listData);
  }
}

// DataBlocSearchDelegate

class IndexedItem {
  final String item;
  final int index;

  IndexedItem(this.item, this.index);
}

abstract class DataBlocSearchDelegate<DB extends DataBloc, R>
    extends SearchDelegate<R> {
  Widget buildListDataWidget(BuildContext context, List<IndexedItem> listData);

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () => close(context, null),
      icon: const BackButtonIcon(),
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () => query = '',
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<DB, DataState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        Widget body;
        if (state is DataLoadingSuccess) {
          body = buildListDataWidget(
            context,
            state.listData
                .asMap()
                .entries
                .map((e) => IndexedItem(e.value, e.key))
                .where((indexedItem) => indexedItem.item
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                .toList(),
          );
        } else if (state is DataInitial || state is DataLoadingInProgress) {
          body = Text('Loading...');
        } else {
          body = Text('Invalid state: $state');
        }
        return body;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```